# Why do notes have multiple names?

Tags: theory, chords, scales, chord-theory, intervals

I've seen the same note called different names for example the note F# can also be written as Gb. Why is this the case and are there times to use one name over another?

Comment: On the hazard of not surprising anyone: I would refute the premise of this question. Notes **don't** have multiple names (...except do-re-mi vs C-D-E...). Rather, there are different notes which happen to come out at the same frequency if you render them in certain tuning systems.

Comment: I actually disagree with you, leftroundabout. I usually consider enharmonic notes to be one and the same in twelve-tone equal temperament tuning.

Comment: When I saw the title I thought it was about how e.g. here in Germany B means Bb and H means B. Which can be confusing in a band with several nationalities, and when playing sheet music from another country.

Comment: @LaurencePayne you can ask and answer your own questions if you want. The system is specifically set up for this. This question came from a lot of questions dancing around this idea, but not actually asking the question.

Comment: @Kevin It depends a lot on the style. I read a jazz theory book which stated in chapter one that all enharmonic equivalents were simply the same. In classical music, they are very important. In theory (harmony) you need them for the direction of a note (e.g. C# goes to D, Db goes to C, not the other way around). In practice, ensembles without an instrument with fixed tuning (string quartet, wind ensemble, a Capella choir, etc) treat them differently, because these ensembles aren't bound to twelve-tone equal temperament tuning (or any tuning, you can just intonate pure intervals in many cases).

Comment: Note: edit rolled back per https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/do-we-accept-edits-that-simply-update-the-characters-used-for-accidentals

Comment: You asked a question you already know the answer to?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis see comment to Laurence.

Comment: I saw your comment, but not Lawrence's.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis he asked the same question in the comments in a more colorful way that was flagged, but the answer is the same. It can be done to help fill in question that aren't on the site yet that you want to answer.

Comment: I noticed a few members with very high reputation have a lot of old questions, self answered, with lots and lots of up votes. I guess if you were an early member of this forum you could justify it as "seeding" the site. But it pretty much just presenting textbook content, not answering a question.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I answered and shaped the question based on the issues I was seeing at the time and tried to provide common examples. It's not perfect, but I do think my answer address the core question the provides extra details to show it in action.

Comment: @Kevin I don't think you really do.  If G flat and F sharp were truly one and the same, there would be nothing wrong with writing Mary Had a Little Lamb in D major using the pitches G flat, E, and D.  But there _is_ something wrong with that.  (And this applies to every 12-tone temperament, equal or unequal.)

Comment: @Phoog I usually work with music in my DAW on my computer. For better or for worse, most DAWs treat enharmonic notes the same. In fact, I believe mine only uses sharps instead of flats, so in the key of Bb, I'd write Mary had a Little Lamb with A#, C, and D! I'd definitely make sure to use the clearest and most conventional notation to communicate with another musician, but when I'm actively producing, I have to be comfortable thinking about enharmonic notes as interchangeable.

Comment: @Kevin that your DAW models its domain imperfectly doesn't change the fact the the domain model is imperfect.  Your needing to be comfortable with it is a fault of the software.  You concede this point by mentioning conventional notation, which this question is about.  Obviously there are contexts in which it makes no sense to differentiate between A sharp and B flat, most notably identifying keys on a keyboard without connection to of a piece of music or a tonality, but _in_ that context, the choice isn't arbitrary, and forcing users to use one or the other is poor domain modeling.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The reason there are multiple names for notes is that the same note may function differently in different contexts. If you just play a single note with no context, then it could have a multitude of different names. For example if you played the note in between F and G you could call it **F#** or **Gb** or more obscurely [E##](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/87/purpose-of-double-sharps-and-double-flats) or [Abbb](http://dictionary.onmusic.org/terms/3683-triple_flat). They are all valid names and are referred to as **enharmonic equivalents**, but if you gave more context like you were playing the G major scale or playing a Db minor chord certain note names would make more sense.  Typically notes are named based on the *scale*, *chord* or *interval* they are in.

### Scales

For this, we'll just look at examples in 12 tone Equal Temperament, where are [12 unique notes](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24/why-are-there-twelve-notes-in-an-octave) that repeat every octave. A majority of scales in music [contain 7 notes](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/8173/the-major-scale-why-and-how). Each scale degree gets a letter from A to G based on the root of the scale and type of scale. The naming convention for the 12 notes makes the C major scale have no accidentals in it. Using the scale pattern for major the C Major scale has the notes `C,D,E,F,G,A,B,C` and can be seen below.

[image]

The C major scale has only naturally named notes and the pattern is nice and simple. No accidentals and you see one of each letter name. If we were to start the major scale on D, we would have the notes `D,E,F#,G,A,B,C#,D` as shown below.

[image]

Like C major you see one of each letter name, but now there are two accidentals F# and C#. Because of the major scale pattern these notes are named this way. Their enharmonic equivalent Gb and Db would not make sense in this context as if they were used we would have the notes `D,E,Gb,G,A,B,Db,D` as shown below.

[image]

If the D major scale's notes were named this way there would never be an F or C and [key signatures](http://www.musictheory.net/lessons/24) would be useless.

### Intervals

[Intervals are named](http://musictheoryblog.blogspot.com/2007/01/intervals.html) based on how far the letters are apart from each other and then by how far the notes are from each other. Because of this the name of the notes affect what the interval is. One example is the notes C to Eb make a minor 3rd which is a common interval seen below.

[image]

The notes are C and Eb are a 3rd apart and it can be seen from the skip from one line to another. The enharmonic equivalent of Eb (which is D#) is not a third away thus the interval of C to D# is an Augmented 2nd instead of a minor third.

[image]

They sound the same, but they function differently. These intervals are the building blocks of many chords and whether a note is a 3rd or 2nd away makes a difference.

### Chords

Chords are a collection of 2 or more notes (usually at least 3) and typically they are built in 3rds. The intervals between each of the root note and the other notes is how the chord is named. For example a C minor chord has the notes C, Eb, and G in it. From the C to the Eb is a minor 3rd and the C to the  G is a perfect 5th.

[image]

Because chords are defined by their intervals, typically there is only one enharmonic equivalent that is appropriate to spell the chord. If D# was used instead of Eb the chord would look like the this.

[image]

It is not easy to see that the D# is acting as the 3rd of the C minor chord because it looks like a second. If there are double flats or sharps in a score most likely it is to show what a certain note is functioning as in a chord. For example a C fully diminished chord is spelled C, Eb, Gb, Bbb and consists of a root, minor 3rd, diminished 5th, and diminished 7th.

[image]

Typically someone will write the enharmonic equivalent of Bbb (A) to avoid someone reading double flats.

---

The above is show within the context of Equal Temperament, but the idea is the same if not more important in other temperaments. The only difference is that in other temperaments is not all the harmonic equivalents used above are the same frequency so the distinction is much more important as writing for example an A♯ vs a B♭ will sound different.

Comment: It's worth noting that it's true in Equal Temperament system.

Comment: It's also true for Just Intonation, Meantone Intonation, and microtones as well...

Comment: @Dom - It's also true of other musicians as well; people don't like reading double flats. :) Also, small nitpick - chords can have two notes, they're called *diads*.

Comment: Another small nitpick: C-to-D# doesn't just "look" like a second; it *is* a second (albeit an augmented second). +1 nonetheless.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes Unfortunately, it's not that simple. All kinds of complicated mathematical stuff happens when using untempered intonation. For starters, you might get more than twelve notes in an octave; adding 12 pure fifths (derived from the overtone series) doesn't yield the same distance as adding 7 pure octaves (overtone-series derived), so in this case a B# is not the same pitch as a C, if you start adding fifths and octaves from a low C. This is known as the [Pythagorean comma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_comma).

Comment: @Dom This is a solid answer. However, I'd start to really like it if it at least touched on the horribly complicated labyrinth of tuning issues and it's consequences for enharmonic equivalents. Sentences like "there are 12 unique notes (...)" only work in a tempered tuning system.

Comment: @11684 I'd rather not open up that can of worms on this question as I can double the size of the post and really confuse beginners more than it can help, but I'll clean up the wording a bit.

Comment: @11684 Of course, however as Dom implied, information is relevant to context. When I explain time signatures to little kids, I can't go into every possible configuration and meaning. Since we're discussing pythagorean commas, why not eschew the absurdity of fixed-pitch tones altogether and instead talk about Ben Johnston's approach of ratios? If the OP wants to dive deeper into those topics, they're more than welcome to. But it's not my job (or anyone else's) to regurgitate swaths of music theory for every question posted.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes Fair enough. But in your first comment you stated this answer was also true for other tuning systems, which it isn't. Omitting the whole tuning discussion is best for a beginner, but I'd rather confuse a beginner than give false information.

Comment: I'd say that C-Eb-Gb-Bbb and C-Eb-Gb-A are chords with the same pitches but different names: The first is a Cdim7 in root position, the second is an Adim7 in first inversion (65).

Comment: I don't understand all the concern about tuning systems. The matter of enharmonic spelling is one of _notation_.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I only mentioned it in passing to say they are not the same exact pitch all the time and that should be kept in mind.

Comment: This is a great answer, but it answers the "how" not the "why". It's tautological to say the reason that the notes have multiple names is because they function differently in different contexts. After all, you can call a note the "wrong" name but its harmonic function won't change if the context hasn't. The answer to "why" is because the diatonic major scale is at the core of Western music theory, and as other answers point out, notes in a scale must be sequential according to alphabetic order. The rest is the natural result of modulation through different key centers.

Comment: @bazeblackwood it's explained in the first paragraph. The different contexts are important. The rest of the answer goes into examples of that context and why the name of the note matters and why notes have multiple names

Comment: "The above is show[n] within the context of equal temperament...": It applies to every twelve-tone temperament.  For example, the interval between F sharp and B flat is the same in any given twelve-tone temperament as the interval between G flat and B flat; it's just that in some temperaments, some major thirds or diminished fourths will be poorly tuned.  But there's no 12-tone temperament where it would be correct to spell the leading tone of G minor as G flat.

Comment: In fact, any song in F♯ major (regardless of how the key is written) would have to use one seemingly ridiculous accidental (for example, E♯).

Answer (score 12):

The multiple names of the notes occur because of the Strict Alphabetic Rule, which states that: 


Each of the 7 notes in a standard scale MUST have its own letter of the alphabet.


This rule is because the lines and spaces on the Music Clef do NOT represent notes, they only represent LETTERS of the ALPHABET.

For example on the bottom line of the Standard Treble Clef, the E line, you could write any of the following notes:

Ebb (E Double-flat), Eb, E (Natural), E#, or E X (E ## or E Double-sharp). 


The notes above are all COMPLETELY different sounds. The only thing they have in common is that they are notated in terms of the letter E.

In simpler terms, of course, these are the notes D D# E F and F#, and that's exactly how those notes are played!

With this ancient and very clever system you can always get a scale note to have ITS OWN line or space on the Music Clef.

To get a quick grasp of what I mean, play these scales, which all have completely different sounds, but all use the same 7 alphabet letters in the same order:

(#=sharp, b=flat, bb=double-flat, X =## or doublesharp)

D  Major:          D  E  F# G  A  B   C# D
D  Harmonic Minor: D  E  F  G  A  Bb  C# D
D  Melodic Minor : D  E  F  G  A  B   C# D

Db Major:          Db Eb F  Gb Ab Bb  C  D
Db Harmonic Minor: Db Eb Fb Gb Ab Bbb C  Db 
(Fb played as E, Bbb played as A) 
Db Melodic Minor : Db Eb Fb Gb Ab Bb  C  Db

D# Major:          D# E# FX G# A# B#  CX D# 
(E# sharp played as F, 
FX or F## or F Double sharp played as G, 
B# sharp played as C, 
CX or C## or C Double sharp played as D) 

D#  Harmonic Minor: D# E# F# G# A# B  CX D# 
D#  Melodic Minor  : D# E# F# G# A# B# CX D#

Daft though this may seem to the beginner, these are the correct notations ("spellings") of these scales.

Major Scales are easiest learned in the order of Cycle of Fifth, Cycle of Fourths, and should be learned in tandem with both of thier relative minors.

If you want to start to be a superior muscian, you might want to get cracking on the first 7 in the cycle right away:


(H/M = Harmonic/Melodic)


Cycle of Vths---------------------Cycle of IVths

C Major,  A H/M Minor     -----C Major,   A H/M Minor   
G Major,  E H/M Minor     -----F Major,   D H/M Minor   
D Major,  B H/M Minor     -----Bb Major,  G H/M Minor   
A Major,  F# H/M Minor    -----Eb Major,  C H/M Minor   
E Major,  C# H/M Minor    -----Ab Major,  F H/M Minor   
B Major,  G# H/M Minor    -----Db Major,  Bb H/M Minor  
F# Major, D# H/M Minor    -----Gb Major,  Eb H/M Minor  
C# Major, A# H/M Minor    -----Cb Major,  Ab H/M Minor  

Enjoy!

Comment: The strict alphabetic rule is a useful tool, but it seems more observational than explanatory.  That is, it's another feature of the system that the question asks about rather than being an answer to the question.  If I were an elementary music student seeking to learn why G sharp can also be called A flat, my first reaction to this answer would not be "aha, that explains it!"  It would be "why must each of the 7 notes in a standard scale have its own letter of the alphabet?"

Answer (score 8):

Western music is mostly built around diatonic scales -- made up of 7 notes from the 12 notes you get by dividing an octave into 12 semitones.

The "standard" diatonic scale is the major scale, which is is defined as:

- root note
- up 2 semitones
- up 2 semitones
- up 1 semitone
- up 2 semitones
- up 2 semitones
- up 2 semitones
- up 1 semitones (reaches 1 octave from the root -- double the frequency)

(The minor scale is just as "standard", and just has a slightly different pattern)

If you start on C, and count up those semitones, you'll find that they all fall on notes that are neither sharps nor flats - C,D,E,F,G,A,B,C  (it's easiest to do this at a piano keyboard).

If you start on another note, you'll find that you land on some sharps or flats.

For example D major: D, E, F♯, G, A, B, C♯, D

... or F major: F, G, A, B♭, C, D, E

One way to think about playing music, is to say "Right, I'm playing in F major, and so whenever I see a B, I'll play B♭."

That's the approach taken when writing music on a stave. The *key signature* signifies that all Bs are to be flattened. Then, unless marked with an *accidental*, everything written as a B should be played as a B♭.

So to your question, why sometimes call that note B♭ and other times A♯?

If you think of F major as F, G, A, A♯, C, D, E -- then it's a more complicated system to think about.

With B♭, it's a scale with all the notes, B flattened.

With A♯, it's a scale with all the notes except B; A is sometimes natural, sometimes sharpened. If you write a score using this system, you'd have very frequent accidental marks cluttering the score.

This is sometimes called "the alphabet rule" -- a scale has all the letters of the musical alphabet, A to G.

So, that's why, when playing in F major, we call the black note between A and B, "B♭".

But when would we call it A♯?

B major contains an A♯:  B, C♯, D♯, E, F♯, G♯, A♯. A♯ and B♭ are the same piano key; the same fret on a guitar. But in the context of a F major scale it's easier to call it B♭ -- because there is an A natural in the scale. And in the context of a B major scale it's easier to call it A♯, because there is a B natural in the scale.

---

On a piano, where tunings are locked-in, A♯ and B♭ have exactly the same pitch. On instruments where the player has more control of the pitch, they'll often play the two notes differently. This is because the tuning of a piano is a compromise, with different notes being more or less in exact tune, depending on the key one is playing in. That compromise is necessary because the physics of vibrating strings isn't quite consistent with the practice of dividing an octave into 12 semitones. The details of this are probably beyond the scope of the question as asked.

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers the question.  It's mostly an aside until you say the answer is beyond the scope of the question.  At minimum I think you should show when A# is useful.

Comment: @MatthewRead Really? I think from "So to your question" to the horizontal line, is *the* answer, at the questioner's level. Below the HR is there for pedants.

Comment: I agree with Matthew here: I think the thought and intention is good, however I think the reasoning could be a bit more developed. For example, you didn't mention anything about Tetrachords, use of enharmonics to suggest harmonic function, contextual enharmonic use, or the alphabet rule, to name a few.

Comment: I describe "the alphabet rule" although I have never heard it called that before. Will update to name it. I infer from the wording of the question that harmonic function, tetrachords etc. are way too advanced for the questioner's level.

Comment: @MatthewRead: A major scale starting on B would contain the notes B, C#, D#, E, F#, G#, A#, B.  Since the first/last note is B, the note before needs to be some kind of "A"; since it's only a half-step below "B", that means it must be A#.

Comment: I like this answer (even though I just criticized the answer that says "because of the alphabet rule").  It is a better answer because it explains the mechanics underlying the alphabet rule (preserving relative intervals in different keys in the context of standard staff notation) and it does so in terms that ought to make sense to someone who is relatively new to music theory (someone who might be asking "Why do notes have multiple names?").  I can't imagine how tetrachords would be useful for that (@jjmusicnotes, where's your answer?).

Answer (score 2):

Your questions implies that F# and Gb are the same thing which is not exactly true, depending on the instrument you're playing.

Actually it is a fundamental question about why music is written with 7 notes.

Basically, since you were born, your ear is accustomed to hear harmonics that are produced naturally. When a tree is struck, you hear a sound with a frequency, say a A with 220 vibrations per second, but you hear also double the frequency (440) which is an octave and also triple (660) which is the fifth above the octave.

So our ancestors decided that to define music alphabet we needed to have a reference where each note would also have its octave and fifth.

With these constraints they remarked you could build a scale of only 12 notes that would, almost, obey the rules :

F -> C -> G -> D -> A -> E -> B -> F# -> C# -> G# -> D# -> A# -> E# (~F)

Almost, because the maths don't really compute : when you take the fifth inside the same octave basically you are multiplying the frequency by 3 (then dividing it by 2 if needed, to stay in the same octave).

By hoping to circle back to where you start (F), you are hoping that a multiple of 3 (fifth) will one day be a multiple of 2 (octave). That won't happen.

You still have a mismatch of 3^12/2^19 = 531441 / 524288 = 1,0136 or 1,36%

And this is where the trouble began.
This little error, which is roughly one ninth of a tone, called a comma, can be heard and be played, and sung.

So, in their great wisdom, our ancestors, beginning with Pythagoras, born 580 BC, tried to respect the purity of the fifth.
What this meant was that, depending where you started in the scale, (A,B,C,D,E,F, G), you had not exactly the same intervals, not exactly the same half-tones precisely.

This led, roughly in XVIIth century, to the introduction of the flat, abbreviation b (from bemol or soft B in italian ), who was built symmetrically to the sharp # but going downward.

B -> E -> A -> D -> G -> C -> F -> Bb -> Eb -> Ab -> Db -> Gb -> Cb (~B)

And they had not he same value. You had approximately 1/9 of a tone difference between the F# and the Gb. The reason why we needed both.

However, that made things horribly complicated when you wanted to have different instruments play together. For tuning, it was a nightmare.

The idea that we could cheat a little on the fifth in order to simplify all this mess finally took up, and gradually the "equal temperament" (every halftone equal) became more and more accepted, especially in multi-instrument concerts, and by writing the "well-tempered clavier" in 1720, Bach laid a milestone.

For centuries there was coexistence of the different tunings and musicians got used to differentiate flats and sharps because sometimes, it mattered.

And as a consequence they even got used to write scales even when it didn't matter, for example on the piano, where you can't play differently a flat and a sharp.

Gradually, instruments that could not differentiate between the two, keyboards, guitars, most horns, became the norm, the equal temperament the de facto standard  and the idea that there was a difference between sharp and flat finally forgotten by most.

Comment: Did you really mean "tree"?  Also, the flat was introduced in the 11th century, not the 17th(!!!).  Sharps were first used much later, in the 16th century if I recall correctly.  But the answer to this question does not lie in tuning.  For example, there is no temperament in which it is correct to spell the third of a D major chord as G flat.

Comment: Also, "abbreviation b (from bemol or soft B in italian)": the flat is called _bemol_ because it has the form of _b_, not the other way around.  It has the form of _b_ because it was originally (in the 11th century) used to distinguish the two possible pitches between A and C in the scale, one a half step above A and the other a whole step above A.  They were both called B, and both written as "b" but one was round or soft and the other was square or hard.  Only later (but still well before the 17th century -- where does that idea come from?) was the sign applied to other pitches.

Comment: The concept of half-tone i.e the fact that you need to define new notes  which are separated half a tone from the others, to complete the circle of fifth, comes from Pythagoras. The term in latin for this half-tone was diesis itself borrowed from greek. Diesis has been kept as is in Italian and became dièse in french and means sharp.

Comment: Pythagoras didn't complete the circle of fifths.  The 12-tone scale didn't arise until the late middle ages or the early renaissance.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_system_of_ancient_Greece and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(music). We call Pythagorean tuning by that name because Pythagoras developed the concept of building a _diatonic_ scale using the 3:2 fifth, but beyond that the 12-tone system has little to do with Pythagoras.  I'm still curious why you think that the flat was introduced in the 17th century.

Comment: I’ll make it clearer for you
- building on Pythagoreas observations of the fifths, the ancient Greeks invented the diatonic scale that allowed 12 notes to build various (7 notes) scales on different tonics and different modes (dorian, myxolidian, …)
- an invention now summed up as « circle of the fifths »
- that for, they needed to up notes by a half-tone, they call it δίεσις (diesis), which later will become diesus and dièse (sharp in english). Hence my presentation that the concept of upping the note (dièse) is anterior to downing it (bémol).

Comment: - The difference is a comma, which is the topic of my post
- Chromatic scales were massively introduced in the 17th century, even if you can find appearances in the 16th

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're talking about now, but the Pythagoreans simply weren't using 12 fixed pitch classes to "build various scales on different tonics and modes." The δίεσις is just the interval left over after dividing some other interval into smaller parts; in Greek theory it was smaller than a semitone; only later it was the remaining interval after inserting two 9:8 tones into a 4:3 fourth (the interval between E and F, for example).  That it refers to chromatic alteration is a much later development.

Comment: The need to contend with the Pythagorean comma only arose with the 12-key keyboard in the 15th century, and even then it probably didn't become a problem before the syntonic comma became an issue: nobody would have cared about a wolf fifth between A♭ and E♭ or C♯ and G♯ until rather later, and by that time they had already begun experimenting with "split" keys so (e.g.) the third of an E major chord didn't have to serve as the root of an A♭ major chord.  It was the unwieldy nature of the more-than-twelve-tone keyboards that led to the abandonment of meantone temperament.

Comment: You’re misunderstanding the topic of my post, which is to say that the basis for a 12 notes system derives from physics and mathematics and that the foundations of it were identified by Pythagoricians, who had to deal with these problems as the modal melodies and the cord instruments they used (Lyras) made this necessary to avoid dissonances. The fact that this was not perfect did indeed appear later with chromatism and the introduction of dièse and bémol and the understanding of the comma difference between the two

Answer (score 1):

Fast, simple answer.

- Each note name, i.e. the letter name, can only be used once in naming notes of the scale.
- Everything refers to major scale, built: W-W-H-W-W-W-H
- Use every letter A -> G only ONE time in naming scale.
   (start on letter of key, e.g. -> E for E major, etc.

**Example:**

D major.  Following major scale formula you get: D E F# G A B C#

- Why the sharps, instead of flats?  Use each letter only once.  So, you can't go D E Gb G because you are using the G twice.
- Just lay out all the letters, starting with the key you are in, and then sharp or flat as necessary.

  ```
      Bb for example:   B C D E F G A -> becomes -> Bb C D Eb F G A

      Eb: E F G A B C D -> becomes -> Eb F G Ab Bb C D

      E:  E F G A B C D -> becomes -> E F# G# A B C# D#
  ```

and so forth.  Other posts get more technical and in depth, but this is the easy way to remember.

Comment: This is not true you get 5, 6 and 12 note scales

Answer (score 0):

The pitch letter system uses only 7 letters for 12 pitches (and their octave transpositions) and alters the 7 letters with sharps or flats to derive the other 5 of 12 pitches.

The distance between pitches in music is called an *interval.* I won't detail interval naming completely, but suffice to say the basic interval type is determined by the 7 letters with specific qualities determined by sharp/flat/natural signs.

The correct naming of intervals is an important aspect of harmony, and so choosing the right letter to get the right interval name matters. `D` to `F#` the interval of a major third, and `D` to `Gb` the interval of a diminished fourth, may appear to be the same on a keyboard, but they are two different intervals. The "sameness" of `F#` and `Gb` can be referred to a *enharmonic equivalence*, and you can call one choice or the other a *spelling.* Spelling and notating intervals correctly is important for making tonal harmony clear.

If you need a metaphor, thing of correct spelling in English: *If eye jest make up mai own spelling, its hord two reed.* When someone learns how to read notation and studies tonal harmony, reading enharmonically misspelled notes is as annoying as reading that misspelled English.

One way to demonstrate the difference in enharmonic spelling, intervals, and how you might get either `F#` or `Gb` is to just follow a series of ascending or descending perfect fifths. If you ascend from `C` you will eventually arrive at `F#`. But if you descend from `C` you will eventually arrive at `Gb`. Then end points are enharmonically the same, but you spell them differently, because of the intervals and direction of movement.

```
C G D A E B F#
```

```
C F Bb Eb Ab Db Gb
```

Answer (score -1):

Thete exist more names still. They are called Technical Names. They are in relation to the key you are in.

They are the Tonic (1st note of scale)
Super Tonic (Second note)
Mediant (Third note)
Sub Dominant (Fourth note)
Dominant (Fifth note)
Sub Mediant (Sixth note)
Leading Tone (Seventh note)

The 8th note in the scale is the tonic repeated.

Answer (score -2):

So you don't have two notes in the scale with the same letter as that would be awful when writing the dots on the music lines thingy.

Comment: This is already covered by other answers.

Comment: Maybe but in very complicated terms not actually necessary to provide an answer to the question..