# Can multiple instruments make a chord?

Tags: chords, harmony, chord-theory, chord-voicings, multi-instrumentalism

This seems in line with the definition of [chord](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chord)

"three or more musical tones sounded simultaneously"

But do people commonly refer to a chord coming from multiple instruments? Then any set of instruments can make chords, whether the same or different types even.

Comment: Well, not strictly *any* set of intruments - you won't get a chord out of a bunch of unpitched percussions - but most you can hear in practice.

Comment: It's almost certain that chords were produced in this way (probably with more than one voice) before instruments which could produce chords on their own.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, any collection of instruments can make a chord. "Chord" just means several simultaneous, different pitches, and the various terms like "major" and "minor" designate particular characteristic chord constructions. The concepts are instrument independent.

Comment: Including, I would note, the human voice.

Comment: @phoog and hand bell choirs.

Comment: @phoog ... and the [muppophone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaL6s4eNNBg)

Comment: Simultaneous pitches - unless its a broken chord.

Answer (score 3):

It could be added, if it's not obvious, that voices can also make chords.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic [One randomly found example.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpLsLuuVmtk) It's very common for choirs and vocal groups to do this.

Comment: Oh, and [one notorious example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-VAxGJdJeQ&t=86s)... sorry about the sopranos being out of key.

Comment: OH, thank you! Sorry, I think I misinterpreted your answer, you mean voices like "a collection of human voices", not "a single voice making a chord". I was thinking that'd be some impressive singing. I think I've seen some people who can do similar/weird stuff but still curious. Thank you!

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic Yeah, the technique is called overtone singing and let's you project several tones simultanously, eg. [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vC9Qh709gas)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, absolutely! Stuff like, say, a whole symphonic orchestra playing the final chord of a piece is something you can definitely hear about using just these words. First violins contribute one tone, flutes another, and so on - all together, it's a chord.

Answer (score 1):

One concrete example is with complex chords on a guitar, e.g. [11th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleventh_chord) or [13th](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteenth).

They might be hard or impossible to play (there are 7 notes in a 13th chord, and only 6 strings). One solution is to [leave out the root](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/32950/40510). It will most probably be played by the bass or piano, and the whole will sound like a chord.

Answer (score 0):

Certain instruments, like horns and woodwinds, can only sound one note at a time. To produce a chord, several of them would need to sound the component notes simultaneously.

Comment: It's probably reasonable to say that *most* instruments can only sound one note at a time. Keyboard and string instruments are the exceptional ones.