# Does the key signature change how I notate a diminished seventh chord?

Tags: chords, notation, chord-theory, harmony

When notating a piano score, and a C diminished seventh chord must be notated, I do not know what conventions to follow.   How does the key signature govern the notation?  For example, assume the music is in the key of C. If so, as I understand it, the following be correct:  C--Eb--Gb -- A.   Would it be acceptable to identify the notes as C -- D#  -- F# -- A?   Suppose the music were in the key of Ab (four flats)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do notes have multiple names?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23976/why-do-notes-have-multiple-names)

Answer (score 8):

How you spell chords does not depend on the governing key signature. Instead, you want to spell chords how they function.

But before I explain that, let's address the C fully diminished seventh chord. Keep in mind that these are *tertian* sonorities, meaning they are built in thirds. This means you want each note to be spelled a third above the previous note. As such, a C fully diminished seventh chord is properly spelled `C E♭ G♭ B♭♭`, because each note is a third above the prior note.

Spelling that last pitch as an A technically wouldn't work, because G♭ to A is only a second. If you spell that pitch with an A, you're actually spelling an A fully diminished seventh chord, because the stacked thirds are built on A: `A C E♭ G♭`. Similarly, your `C D♯ F♯ A` is really a D♯ fully diminished seventh chord.

Now, back to the first paragraph, when I say you want to spell chords the way that they function. One role of fully diminished seventh chords is to resolve to a chord a half step above the diminished chord's root. As such, if the next chord is D♭, you'll want to spell it as a C diminished seventh chord. But if the next chord is B♭, it's better to spell it as an A diminished seventh chord to show the half-step relationship between the diminished seventh chord and the next chord.

Comment: Another thing to note is there are only four fully-diminished 7th chords, but the inversion of the chords and enharmonic spellings indicate how they are being used.

Comment: There are only three.

Answer (score 3):

The C dim7 chord is 'properly' spelt C, Eb, Gb, Bbb.  A pile of minor thirds, encompassing the interval of a diminished 7th.

In practice, it will often be spelt C, Eb, Gb, A, or even  C, Eb, F#, A.    Not because it's harmonically correct, but because it's easier to read.   And, in practice, although we're quite fussy about not mis-spelling leading notes and minor 7ths -  a G#7 chord includes B# not Ab, a Db7 chord has Cb not B - we don't fuss so much over correct spelling of diminished 7th chords.

[image]

The rules may be applied more rigorously in a harmonic analysis of course.   And some jazz players tolerate, or even prefer, spellings that obscure the function of a leading note, writing e.g. an F# scale with F natural and F# instead of E# and F#.  (Alto sax players DO find themselves in this territory, particularly in guitar-based styles!)

Comment: It's not just wrong; it's a German aug. 6.

Answer (score 1):

Just answering the last part, as Richard's done a super job with the rest, as always.

In key Ab, the dim7 chord is spelled Ab Cb Ebb Gbb, which may sound awkward, but there it is. There it *isn't* Ab B D F - honest !

Comment: It's analysed as that, yes.   But you'll very rarely see it SPELLED that way!

Comment: @LaurencePayne - in USA it's spelt like that a lot ! And we do have a few readers from the States...

Comment: It's spelled with a Gbb in British harmony manuals too.   But not so often in music for performance.   On either side of the pond, I suspect!   Or have you got examples?