# Is Cmaj7 in the C major scale different than the Cmaj7 in the C Dorian scale?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, harmony

I was told that the 7 in Cmaj7 indicates the 7th scale degree.

But here's what's confusing to me: in the C major scale, the 7th scale degree is B. And the interval from the root note of the Cmaj7 chord to the 7th would be a M7.

However, in the C Dorian scale, the 7th scale degree is A#, and the interval from the root note of Cmaj7 to the 7th would be a m7.

So if the number 7 in Cmaj7 really indicates the 7th scale degree, then does that mean Cmaj7 in C major scale is different than Cmaj7 in C Dorian scale?

Comment: Cmaj7 is Cmaj7. There is no Cmaj7 made up from the notes in C Dorian. There will be Bb maj7 and Eb maj7 instead.  There is no A# note in C Dorian. It's Bb.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C Ionian is `C D E F G A B`, whereas C Dorian is `C D E♭ F G A B♭`. (Note that this last pitch is *not* A♯, as you wrote.)

When you say that "the 7 in Cmaj7 indicates the 7th scale degree," I have one small adjustment: "the 7 in Cmaj7 indicates the 7th scale degree *of the major scale*" (hence the *maj* 7).

So in C Ionian (or C Major), the seventh chord built on C is Cmaj7, because the pitches are `C E G B`, taken straight from the C-Ionian collection.

But in C Dorian, the chord will be `C E♭ G B♭`, which creates a Cm7 chord.

In short, I think your confusion lies in the distinction between "Cmaj7" and "the seventh chord built on C." The quality of the seventh chord built on C will not always be maj7; instead, it will change depending on the current key signature.

Answer (score 19):

CMaj7 always has the notes C E G B regardless of the context around it. In general terms, any major 7th chord contains a root, Major 3rd, Perfect 5th, and Major 7th. It is naturally built in the C major scale by building a chord starting on C in 3rds, but it does not stop you from using it elsewhere even when the notes are not naturally found in the key/scale you are playing. You can play this in any key and it will contain the same notes.

You also seem to be confused with what C Dorian is. C Dorian not only does not have the B, but it also has no E. The notes of the C Dorian scale are as follows:

```
C D Eb F G A Bb C
```

If you naturally wanted to build a seventh chord off the root of the scale, it would be Cm7 which contains the notes C, E♭, G, and B♭ or in other terms contain a root, minor 3rd, Perfect 5th, and minor 7th.

Also note: there is no A♯ in C Dorian. The note is B♭ since if you spelled it as A♯ you would have a scale with two As and no Bs. For more information on how notes are named in different contexts, see [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/23976/7222).

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion might arise from a mistaken assumption that the 'maj' in Cmaj7 refers to the 'C'. Actually it refers to the '7'. That is to say, the 7th interval added to the C triad is a *major* 7th.

By convention, major triads have no suffix, minor triads have a 'm' suffix, and  diminshed has 'dim' or '°'.

For the 7th interval the convention is sort of backwards. *Minor* 7th intervals are written just as '7' (minor implied, no prefix), and *major* 7th intervals are written as 'maj7', 'M7', or even just '△' as a shorthand.

Note the upper-case 'M'. If you see Cm7 then that is a C minor triad with a 7th, and because the 7th isn't prefixed with anything (the 'm' belongs to the C) it is a *minor* 7th interval.

Indeed, there is such a thing as a [minor major-7th chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_major_seventh_chord), e.g. C, E♭, G, B, sometimes notated as CmMaj7 although there are many other notations.

Comment: 3rd para. True a '7' without a prefix has a *minor 7th* interval, but the chord produced will either be *minor 7* OR *dominant 7*

Comment: @Tim I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at. I don't think F7 in the key of C major could strictly be called the dominant 7th when it's actually built on the sub-dominant chord (F). If it was being used as a dominant chord then the implied key would be B♭.

Comment: F7 is a dominant 7th even if your intent is not to use it for its dominant function. The feature of a dominant 7th is the tritone between the Major 3rd and the minor 7th makeing it want to resolve the typical dominant-tonic way

Comment: F7 was not mentioned. All I am trying to do is clarify your 3rd para., which comes over (to me) as C7 = Cm7, which it doesn't. It could be phrased a little less ambiguously. Sticking with F7 - any dominant 7 will contain a maj. 3rd and a m7 (b7). whether it's based on a sub-dominant root is immaterial.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've edited my answer for clarity.